# Stored Procedure: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Upon running the sql server it display this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Here is the script for my stored procedure

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(GrossSales)
   FROM cssale
   WHERE EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee) AS [Total Sales],

  (SELECT SUM(GrossSales)
   FROM CSSale
   WHERE RefundStoreDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee) AS [Refunds],

  (SELECT SUM(GrossSales)
   FROM CSSale
   WHERE DateVoided BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee) AS [Voided Items],

  ( SELECT sum(isnull(C.Amount,0)) AS [Discount Amount]
   FROM CSSaleItem B
   LEFT JOIN CSSaleItemDiscount C ON B.CSSaleItemID = C.CSSaleItemID
   LEFT JOIN CSSale A ON A.CSSaleID = B.CSSaleID
   LEFT JOIN CSSaleItemTax D ON B.CSSaleItemID = D.CSSaleItemID
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT CSSaleItemID,
             Amount,
             Tax,
             [Type]
      FROM CSSaleItemTax
      WHERE [Type] = 0) AS vsa ON vsa.CSSaleItemID = B.CSSaleItemID
   WHERE A.EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND A.CashierID = @Employee) AS [Discount],

  (SELECT CashierId
   FROM cssale
   WHERE EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee)AS [Cashier]
```

Answer (score 1):

A sub query can return only one  value.in your code below line may be culprit..

```
  (SELECT CashierId
   FROM cssale
   WHERE EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee)AS [Cashier]
```

You can use cross apply/Outer apply if you want to return all rows returned or use top 1 to restrict to only one row

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is (as the error said), that your sub queries returning more than one Value. It's like you are trying to write the complete column of one table into one cell.

Try to solve this query with `JOINS` instead of this sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

The code below would return multiple rows if the Employee was cashier for more than one sale during the given period.

```
(SELECT CashierId
   FROM cssale
   WHERE EndDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND CashierID = @Employee)AS [Cashier]
```

Instead of using the transnational table (cssales); try using the master/domain table which has Employee to Cashier mapping. This would give unique row every time.